# html code generated by django template

Tags: python, django

Sorry if this is a completely retarded question, but I was wondering if it's possible to see the pure html code generated by a django template. Again, I'm really new to django, so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django templates don't result in HTML code, they [result in a node tree](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). The engine then renders the node tree in order to generate the appropriate output.

Answer (score 2):

It might seem like a slightly obvious answer, but have you tried "View Source" in your browser?

If you want to improve your understanding, read the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system) and check out how Template and Context objects work.